# Is there a way to draw inscribed ellipse in a almost rectangular contour?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ellipse, geometry-surface

I am wondering if there is a way to inscribe an ellipse in almost rectangular contour? I am using openCV findcontours() method in my image and my aim is to fit biggest possible ellipses inside every object in the following image: [image]

Code I am using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



def find_contours(preprocessed, min_perimeter):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(preprocessed,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)        #find contours
    contours_new = []                                                                               #new empty list of contours
    for cnts in contours:                                                                           #looping trough contours
        perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnts,True)                                                        #arc length
        if perimeter > min_perimeter:                                                               #leave only significant contours
            contours_new.append(cnts)      

    return contours_new


min_perimeter = 7000                                                           
img_num = 6
results_path = 'results/'
image_path = 'images/'
mask = image_path+str(img_num)+'_predicted_mask.bmp'                           
empty = np.empty([9452, 6144], dtype=np.uint16)
empty = cv2.cvtColor(empty, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

gray = cv2.imread(mask)                                                        
ret,thresholded_mask = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,0)                           
gray_mask = cv2.cvtColor(thresholded_mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


contours_new = find_contours(gray_mask, min_perimeter)                         
cv2.drawContours(empty, contours_new, -1, (255,255,255), 3)
for cnt in contours_new:

    ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
    cv2.ellipse(empty, ellipse, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imwrite('contours.bmp',empty)
```

Result (as you can see elipses are not inscribed):
[image]

Comment: So have you tried fitting an ellipse to each contour?  What is the result? Where is your code?

Comment: I have just updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried getting the width and height of the bounding boxes of the rectangles from their contours (using the rotated rectangle width, height and angle) and then just drawing an ellipse with those limits for the major and minor diameters. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69

Comment: The problem is that I try to find the middle line of each object. Sometimes they are not completely rectangular so thats why I need to fit ellipse in a first place.

Comment: You just need the center, angle of rotation and the width and height of the box to draw an ellipse. Those can come from the rotated rectangle. See cv2.minAreaRect()